# Which SSD controllers don't use compression?

Tags: ssd, encryption, luks

I'm in the market for an SSD, but I haven't found any information on which SSDs do *NOT* use compression on the controller.

The system it will go into requires full disk encryption (provided via LUKS), and many (all?) of the Sandforce controllers end up crippled when they can't compress writes.

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to SuperUser.com. Full disk encryption has known issues with SSDs. Also, this is treading a fine line with "buying recommendation", which is specifically off-topic for SuperUser.

Comment: Since the question is asking about *controllers*, which are typically used by multiple manufacturers/models, and not "Which SSD should I buy?", I'd say it falls on the on-topic side.

Comment: I agree, which is why I didn't vote to close :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- SSDs using Marvell's 88-series controllers don't use compression. [See here](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/plextor-m3-crucial-m4-octane-performance-pro,3178.html) for a recent round-up which includes many models/suggestions. Note that Intel's 510-series SSDs also use(d) Marvell controllers, but the newer 520 series uses Sandforce.
- Samsung SSDs, using their in-house controllers, also do not use compression.